# PHP Regex issue with not allowed char on end

Tags: php, regex

I have a script which reads text from an image (i'm using tesseract-ocr).
so there i will have some wrong detected numbers and formats.

now i would like to only get prices and NOT prices with percent at match-ending (that would be taxes).

my text:

> ( Preis inkl. 7.  7  % MWST ist 5'067.00)

my regex:

```
$regex = "/\d+[\d \]\/\|o,\'.]*\s*/i";
```

now the result should be **5'067.00** but i'm getting **7.7**

Comment: Your regex does match `7. 7 `. What makes you think it shouldn't? Also please post more examples of input strings and what you want to grab as results.

Comment: I did this one `/\d+[\d \]\/\|o,\'.]*\s*(?![\s%\d.])/i` Tell me if it works for all of your cases,  otherwise can you put more examples plz ?

Comment: @Jeto i know that it's correct that `7.  7` matches but i didn't know how to change the regex to NOT match strings which ends with `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RegEx gets every number without a percentage character at the end:

```
/[\d']+\.\d+(?!\s%|%)/g
```

Here is the demo:
[RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/bLNlQO/3)

Comment: thank you, i'm using this solution with a little bit of modification!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<= )[^ ]*(?=\)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ADCn99/1) to get the last price

- `(?<= )` makes sure your match is preceded by a space
- `[^ ]*` matches anything after the last space
- `(?=\)$)` makes sure there is a `)` at the end of the String

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/ADCn99/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this regex:

```
$regex = '/([\d'.]+)\)?$/i';
```

Explanation:

```
(      start of subpattern
[\d'.] character range with numbers, apostrophe and point
+      match one or more charaters of the character range
)      close subpattern
\)?    look for ) and match if one or none exists
$      look at the end of the string
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TVlbsn/3